# Travis CI to modify same branch

Tags: github, travis-ci

I want to use travis-ci to run a script and commit the result back to the same branch on github. (The script generates a markdown table of contents, but could be anything really). Obviously this causes an issue as travis will then see a new commit and run again ad infinitum. I tried to use

```
if: sender != "Travis CI"
```

In my .travis.yml, but the docs are extremely vague about what exactly 'sender' is matching against, and I see no way to inspect the run time values travis is using.

I use this method: https://gist.github.com/willprice/e07efd73fb7f13f917ea
to commit back to github.

Is there a better way to achieve what I want? Or what is the correct way to make this work with travis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might cleaner ways of doing it but one way is to use the following.

According to [this documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/customizing-the-build/#skipping-a-build), you can simply add a "tag" or specific string to your commit message in order to avoid Travis building it.

Simply add `[ci skip]` or `[skip ci]` to your commit message and Travis will ignore it.

Your function in `push.sh` will become the following:

```
commit_website_files() {
  git checkout -b gh-pages
  git add . *.html
  git commit --message "[skip cp] Travis build: $TRAVIS_BUILD_NUMBER"
}
```

Also you could still push to another branch which wouldn't be watched by Travis.

Hope this helps.